# Javascript cookies - checking if cookie exists

Tags: javascript, cookies

If the cookie doesnt exist I am trying to show a div and when the cookie is set I dont want the div to show anymore (will be hidden in the css)

But I cant get the div to show when it doesnt have a cookie, does anyone know what I am doing wrong please?

```
Cookies.set('mycookie', '1', {
    expires: 7
});

if (Cookies.get('mycookie') === null) {
    $('div').show();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wqsc5hty/

Comment: Your jsFiddle is broken: _Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/master/src/js.cookie.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled._

Comment: Hmmm really? Its setting the cookie in firebug?

Answer (score -1):

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("mycookie") == 0) {
    return false; // cookie is not set
}else{
    return true; // cookie is set
}
```